# How can I set the external interface for my bridge to be the same as my primary interface using networkd?

Tags: bridge, systemd, mac-address

I've created a virtual bridge `bridge0`:

bridge0.netdev:

```
[NetDev]
Name=bridge0
Kind=bridge
```

bridge0.network:

```
[Match]
Name=bridge0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

and attached my primary interface `eth0` to it

eth0.network:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Bridge=bridge0
```

But this changes the MAC address my computer uses for DHCP to be the random MAC address assigned to `bridge0`. Is there a way to keep the physical MAC address assigned to `eth0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manpage of `systemd.netdev` you can add a MAC address in the `[NetDev]` section.

```
[NetDev]
Name=bridge0
Kind=bridge
MACAddress=
```

Just insert the MAC address of `eth0` there.

Comment: This is what I did in the end, but is there any way to make this dynamic? (for example, not having to hard code the MAC address) and are there any problems with the eth0 port having the same MAC address address as the bridge0 port?

Comment: I don't think it is a problem when you only have one physical interface connected to the bridge. As far as I know the default for `systemd.netdev` seems to derive the MAC address from the `machine-id`. Depending on your distribution you could use e.g. *old-school* style *ifcfg-br0* configuration files in RHEL based systems. Not sure about Debian based ones.